# LocalDb Unspecified Initial Catalog?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, sql-server-express, localdb

I've recently been placed on a project using EF 6.0 and Code First principles. The ApplicationDbContext is loaded from this connection string:

```
name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

As you can see there is no specified Initial Catalog, and yet the data is being stored SOMEWHERE? I have searched the LocalDb instance through the file system, MS VS 2013 and SQL Server Management studio.

The problem is the current devs have created a substantial amount of dummy data we don't want to lose. Does anyone know where this data is being stored and/or how it can be retrieved?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user opens a connection without specifying the DB (aka catalog), it gets a connection to his default DB.

If you have not changed the configuration it will most probably be the `master` DB.

You can confimr this using SSMS. Connect to your server, go to Security > Logins, choose the login used to connect to the DB (as you're using Integrated security it must be the user which starts the app, or the application pool user if it's a web app), right click, choose "Properties", and, in the General panel, at the bottom, you'll see what the default DB is.

*NOTE: perhaps I'm not using the exact wording, as I have a localized SSMS, and I am supposing what the translation is.*

Comment: Thank you! Found all my data in the master DB, which was the user default :)